# How to merge bitmaps in android?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap

I was wondering how can I merge couple of bitmaps in Android to create something like this:

[image]

or something like this:
[image]

I suppose that is done by merging two bitmaps, but how do I center the inner bitmap like this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've figured it out:

```
public static Bitmap mergeToPin(Bitmap back, Bitmap front) {
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(back.getWidth(), back.getHeight(), back.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    int widthBack = back.getWidth();
    int widthFront = front.getWidth();
    float move = (widthBack - widthFront) / 2;
    canvas.drawBitmap(back, 0f, 0f, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(front, move, move, null);
    return result;
}
```

The trick that front image has equal height and width, and that that height/width matches the width of the back image (or scaled - I've resized it to 90% of the original pin width).

It doesn't matter if you put circled or squared pin, as long as the position for image (circle or square) has equal width and height. 
Of course, you need to create circular bitmap if you wish to add it to the circled pin :)

Comment: so how to extract it when merge, please

Answer (score 13):

Try this function.

```
private Bitmap createSingleImageFromMultipleImages(Bitmap firstImage, Bitmap secondImage){

Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(firstImage.getWidth(), firstImage.getHeight(), firstImage.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
canvas.drawBitmap(firstImage, 0f, 0f, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(secondImage, 10, 10, null);
return result;
}
```

Hope this helps.